# Create Blank Table when Importing CSV file to SSMS

Tags: ssms

I am trying to load a cv file into SSMS.

1. I Create a table in SMSS with the headers already, it seems like it makes me create headers, It would work better if I could create a blank table then insert using below code.
2. When I load my CSV using the below SQL, it creates the header twice. Once from creation and secondly from csv.

Is there a way to create a blank table and the headers from my csv become the headers?

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by it makes you make headers? Tables don't have headers.

Comment: when I create the table it makes me create column names. When I import the csv it also has column names. Row 1.

Comment: Well yes, you can't have a table without columns... You can't create a columnless table; that makes no sense.

Comment: Use "Import flat file" in SSMS. This will create a new table using header names from the csv file